Why are we not adding Safe Call Operator(?.) instead of Not-Null Assertion(!!) in OkHttp Library Cache Interceptor?
Why are we not adding Safe Call Operator(?.) instead of Not-Null Assertion(!!) in the attached code in Cache Interceptor ? The source code is : https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/7da99460f0bea3d6c217f37eb27ae66616d7bdd2/okhttp/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/internal/cache/CacheInterceptor.kt#L80
// If we don't need the network, we're done.
    if (networkRequest == null) {
      return cacheResponse!!.newBuilder()
          .cacheResponse(cacheResponse.stripBody())
          .build().also {
            listener.cacheHit(call, it)
          }
    }

We are expecting app should not crash.

You would have to ask whoever wrote that code. We cannot tell you what that person was thinking.

My assumption is it conveys the intent of the code better. More specifically, it conveys reliance on logic the compiler cannot verify. If networkRequest is null, then cacheResponse cannot be null, and if it is then an exception should be thrown instead of returning null (which using ?. would do). And for whatever reason networkRequest and cacheResponse must both be nullable (instead of using, e.g., lateinit).

It's hard to answer for the code sample you provided, because we don't know what's the cacheResponse or networkRequest and what is the logic between them.
However, I noticed there is a common misconception that ?. is somehow better or safer than !!. It is not. In most cases crashing application is better than misbehaving application. Application showing an error is better than application showing that the operation succeeded even if it really didn't.
If we describe "code debugging" to be a process of analyzing a misbehaving application or analyzing how it got to an inconsistent state, in order to determine the exact problem that caused it, then replacing !! with ?. is the opposite process. We would have to call it a "code bugging", and this is in fact what it really is. !! would give us a clear error message and a specific place in the code that we have to fix. After replacing it with ?. we only hid the problem and now we have to debug the application to figure out what is going on and that there was a null somewhere.
In other words:

If the logic of our application expects we may have null somewhere and we would like to perform a conditional operation, use ?..
If we expect there is no null somewhere, use !!.

Ideally, we should try to avoid using !! operator by designing our application in a way, that the data is correctly typed as nullable or not. But if we can't do this, and we have to perform some operations on a nullable variable, then simply replacing !! with ?. is shooting ourselves in the foot.

I prefer ?: error("…") or requireNotNull() over !! to make the debugging a little easier. If you use !! you should probably comment the code with why you’re making that assumption, and so you might as well have that explanation in your code so it appears in the stack trace. But of course in cases like the OP’s code, you may be so confident of the non-null assertion that !! is the most applicable solution. Usually though this only happens when working with a Java library so even the !! is unnecessary to treat the reference as non-nullable.

Because Cache Interceptor not nullable, if u wanna use with ?. operator, u can use like this code
if (networkRequest == null) {
    val response = cacheResponse?.newBuilder()
        ?.cacheResponse(cacheResponse.stripBody())
        ?.build()
    response?.let {
        listener.cacheHit(call, it)
    } ?: run {
        // Handle it if null.
    }
    return response
}


The Question was tSafe Call Operator(?.) instead of Not-Null Assertion(!!) in OkHttp Library Cache Interceptor?.
But you answered how to use Safe Call Operator(?.) in OkHttp Library Cache Interceptor?

Note that Non-null assertions !! are generally considered bad practice.
It's not something that compiler ensures. it's like you give the compiler saying "Hey, I guarantee that it will NOT null at runtime and I'm responsible for consequences (NPE) if it is not".
Regardless of best practice, if we know definitively that variable cannot be null, we can safely use not-null assertion operator !!. Otherwise, just use safe call operator.
For example:
private var stringBuilder: StringBuilder? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   setContentView(binding.root)

   stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
   val result = stringBuilder!!.append("Hello")
}

stringBuilder variable is nullable. Compiler does not know that it can't be null when using it. But we know definitively that it cannot be null since we instantiate it before using it. In this case, we can use !! operator.

because you are all-ready add check if its not null then you use !! this operator but if you not check then ?. safe call operator is better if its null in any case.
